# code128 barcode with tilde and asterisk

Tags: barcode, zebra-printers, zpl-ii, code128

I am maintaining a printing program that now requires printing both a ~ and an * in a code128 barcode in zpl.

Currently, I am using the code below that uses the ^FH to represent the tilde in hex:

```
^BCN,120,Y,N,N,N^FH^FDSPECIAL*MAKE_7e123456^FS
```

The barcode prints excluding the * and ~ as 'SPECIALMAKE123456'. Is it possible to print the tilde and asterisk in a zpl code128 barcode?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick guess, since I don't have a ZPLII printer immediately available, I'd try

```
^BCN,120,Y,N,N,A^FH^FDSPECIAL*MAKE_7e123456^FS
```

(note `A` before the `^FH` = Auto-select codeset)

Perhaps also forcing a codeset by `...^FH^FD>:SPECIAL*...` may work, but subset `B` is the default in any case...

---

I located my old A300 printer, and was able to produce the required interpretation line using each of

```
^BCN,120,Y,N,N,A^FH^FDSPECIAL*MAKE_7E123456^FS
^BCN,120,Y,N,N,A^FH^FDSPECIAL_2AMAKE_7E123456^FS
```

Can't find my scanner to verify at present - but the computer room is a mite tidier...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will play around with switching codesets next.

Comment: When printing the code you provided, the label is printing as 'special2Amake7E123456'. should the interpretation line show the * and ~ or is this interpreted at scanning?

Answer (score 0):

It may depends on type of barcode. 
For example, to print in 'barcode 128', you have to change code to code B, by signs `>:`

And: to print tilde ~, type `>=`. To print ^, type `><`. To print >, type `>0`.

Look to zpl documentation, to table with Code 128 Invocation Characters.

My sample zpl code:

```
^XA
^BY2,3,95^FT0,206^BCN,,Y,N
^FD>:caret >< bigger >0 tilde >= end^FS
^PQ1,1,1,Y^XZ
```